# SPAudit Event Name is null

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have activated Auditing on Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and I have a webpart which has a grid which displays the data from spaudit GetEntries method, but in that I cannot see EventName or MachineIP data ??

let me know
Thanks

Comment: Is disabled by design: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/spauditentry-machinename-and-machineip-properties