# SPAuditEntry MachineName and MachineIP properties

Tags: 2013, development, logging, auditing, farm

I am using the SharePoint Audit Query to build a custom audit log system.
For each hit, I need also the machine name or machine IP.
On the object *SPAuditEntry* there are two **MachineName and MachineIP** but are always empty.

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditentry.machineip.aspx) :

> > In SharePoint Foundation, this property is always a null reference

I am using SP2013 Enterprise on prem.
How can I get these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that there properties **are disabled by design** (really? lol).

The values in the MachineIP column and in the MachineName column appear as NULL because of **privacy concerns**. By design, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 works in this manner.

I think is it possible to trace these information looking into IIS Logs.

[Auditing for a site collection in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/939246)
[Why are my SharePoint Audit Logs missing the MachineName and MachineIP data?](http://mrhodes.net/2009/01/02/why-are-my-sharepoint-audit-logs-missing-the-machinename-and-machineip-data-7/)